# #2006 - MySQL server has gone away && phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection

Tags: phpmyadmin

I just recently uninstalled XAMPP and installed WAMP and i got this error
Error
MySQL said: Documentation

## 2006 - MySQL server has gone away

phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

(first  from xampp then wamp.)

Comment: Useful information are appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Does this message still appear after you restart the MySQL daemon/service?

Comment: Yes. i don't know how to fix this there were no changes made and even reinstalled.